# Clickable link in Node output

Tags: node.js, putty, gnome-terminal, io.js

Is there a way to format a string in node such that when I use console.log the address is clickable from the terminal? For instance, when I start a local server up I usually output the port number but I think it would be much more beneficial if I could output: http://localhost:3000 and be able to click the link.

I am using a Ubuntu VM and ssh'ing with PuTTY so that may make a difference.

This regards Node.js. If the terminal cannot display links that is fine but the other questions on SO are not related to Node and offer differing opinions based on the terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a clickable link in my output to a terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992596/how-can-i-make-a-clickable-link-in-my-output-to-a-terminal)

Comment: I don't think this would be a duplicate of that. I know it's related but I am not performing this in a script. One commenter says gnome-terminal does this automatically but it doesn't seem to be the case for Node.js console messages.

Answer (score 2):

This works for OSX [iTerm](https://www.iterm2.com/) terminal :

`cmd`+`click` on any url in the terminal. Opens the url in default browser.

Comment: It doesn't work for me and it works for other links so not any link, apparently.

Comment: @mgol - Hope you are trying in an iTerm terminal?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible in some fully-featured terminal interfaces, but generally speaking, this is not possible to do so reliably for general users. Many (most?) terminal interfaces are (intentionally) mimics of so-called "dumb terminal" interfaces and do not have the concept of a hyperlink.